# Person<Person>, what is <Person>?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I cloned an iOS project from git repository. The project is written in Objective-C.

I saw this code in a header file:

```
@interface Employee: Person<Person> {
   ...
}
```

What does `Person <Person>` mean? I know it indicates `Employee` is a subclass of `Person` but what is the special meaning of `<Person>` ?

Comment: read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html for more info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Employee is a subclass of a class called Person and also conforms to a protocol called Person.

```
@interface MySubclass : MySuperclass <MyProtocol> { ... }
```

Comment: Aha, yes, protocol! Thank you!

Comment: @Leem.fin You should mark an answer as correct if that solves your doubts.

Comment: @VishalSonawane, yes, but you know there is 10min waiting time before an answer can be marked as accepted. So, I was waiting for that :)

Comment: @Leem.fin Ok. I was unaware about it. Sorry.